# whats wrong with this R loop function?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to run a loop function like this:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,19,20,22,23,24,26) 
n<-rep(NA,length(x))
for (ii in 1:length(x)){
  n[ii]<-subset(dat1, Plot==ii)
}
```

However, error message appeared:

```
There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The outputs that I am looking for is 18 individual data n1,n2,n3,n4,n7,...n24&n26 subset from main data `dat1`.

Comment: So... I'll ask it, did you look at the 18 warnings?

Comment: It's probably `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. You're trying to assign a data frame to an element of an atomic vector.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a little trouble understanding what you want to do, but if you have a vector `dat1`, and you want to form a new vector `n` that contains the 1st, 2nd, ..., 26th elements of `dat1`, that's pretty easy to do in R.  Try:

```
> dat1 <- 1:60
> x <- c(1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,19,20,22,23,24,26)
> n <- dat1[x]
> n
 [1]  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 10 13 14 15 16 19 20 22 23 24 26
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is create a "vector" of data.frames, each one corresponding to a certain level of your `Plot` variable, you should be using a `list`, not a `vector`.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,19,20,22,23,24,26) 
n <- list()
length(n) <- length(x)

for (ii in 1:length(x)){
  n[[ii]] <- subset(dat1, Plot==ii)
}
```